# ClassNotFound Exception after deploying war on server (RHE7) that runs wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver from [Module "deployment.CorrelationBuilder.war" from Service Module Loader]
2020-12-29 05:59:01,679 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:199)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,679 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,679 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,679 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,679 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,679 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,679 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at com.ericsson.enable.correlation.cassandra.util.DB2Connection.getRole(DB2Connection.java:20)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,679 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at com.ericsson.enable.correlation.controller.HomeController.viewRules(HomeController.java:77)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,679 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
2020-12-29 05:59:01,680 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
.....
.....
.....
```

I have added ojdbc lib using Deployment Assembly.

It worked fine when tested locally(tomcar server) but when I uploaded it to server side which is running wildfly it gave this error.

What went wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to deploy the application on a vanilla Tomcat installation - I guess you will get the same error. Some something must have happened to your Tomcat, and I guess someone installed the Oracle JDBC driver.

So do the same on Wildfly otherwise that driver simply is not available in that environment. One method could be to simply drop the oracle driver jar with an appropriate XML deployment descriptor in the deployments folder.